# Angular 2 pass array to router queryString

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I would like to pass an array `ids: [1, 2, 3]` to router query string like this: `http://...some-url?ids=1&ids=2&ids=3`, but when I try to use

```
const queryParams = { ids: [1, 2, 3] };
this.router.navigate(['/some-route'], { queryParams });
```

the result is `http://...some-url/some-route?ids=1%2C2%2C3`

Is there a way to add query params with the same key?

Comment: Have you tried `this.router.navigate(['/some-route'], queryParams );` (remove the `{}`)

Comment: I shouldn't do this, because of router navigate parameters: `navigate(commands: any[], extras?: NavigationExtras)`, and `extras` is object witch can contains queryParams object. I can write `this.router.navigate(['/some-route'], { queryParams: {ids: [1, 2, 3]} });`, but I like short form.
(I tried `this.router.navigate(['/some-route'], queryParams )`, it doesn't work)

Comment: @qweasd Please, see this one. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41264722/how-to-handle-multiple-queryparams-in-angular2 
It is solved there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like there is a bug in the router.
Please, check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42505212/7634393

Answer (score 0):

router.navigate is waiting for a named 'queryParams' value.

So, this should work.

```
const queryParams = { ids: [1, 2, 3] };
this.router.navigate(['/some-route'], { queryParams: queryParams });
```

Or,

```
const extras = { queryParams: { ids: [1, 2, 3] }};
this.router.navigate(['/some-route'], extras);
```

Comment: This works the same as my case: generated params like this: `ids=1%2C2%2C3`. And you can write `this.router.navigate(['/some-route'], { queryParams });` it is property shorthand feature and typescript support this.