# How to send array in router navigate?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular6, angular2-routing

Searched for a solution in other questions but nothing helped me..

I wish to redirect to url like,

```
this.router.navigateByUrl('/products');
```

In which i need to pass the array and need to get it it in the component which has the active link `products` using skip location change without showing anything in url.

Array will be like,

```
products = [{"id":1,"name":"Product One","id":2,"name":"Product Three","id":3,"name":"Product Six"}]
```

I need to pass this entire array in router link and need to retrieve it in another component (products) active link using **skipLocation Change true**..

Tried with `sharedService` but i am getting issue of data loading at right point of time and hence i decided to use via router link..

If this is not a good approach, kindly suggest other alternative without using sharedservice..

Comment: Either you can use the Query string or Session Storage to implement this functionality.

Comment: also could create a service to do the same : https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction#!#bidirectional-service

Comment: Use shared service either

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42412110/angular-2-how-to-pass-an-array-to-the-router-using-queryparams/42505212#42505212

Comment: @PardeepJain, Using shared service i am facing problem of latency and so i wish to make this approach..

Comment: @undefined but this is not ever recommended approach you. Using service code could be cleaner and simpler

Comment: Without shared service is there any approach?? Because i am facing problems of fetching data using shared service at right time..

Answer (score 1):

You can use Angular Services for a large data.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs/Subject';

@Injectable()
export class ExampleService {

private subject = new Subject<any>();  

updateRouteData(data) {
    this.subject.next(data);
}

routeData(): Observable<any> {
    return this.subject.asObservable();
}
}
```

**In your components;**

*For set route data;*

```
import { ExampleService } from '/example.service'

export class ComponentOne{

constructor(private exampleService:ExampleService){
   this.exampleService.updateRouteData(data)
}
```

*You can pass data like;*

```
import { ExampleService } from '/example.service'

export class ComponentTwo{

constructor(private exampleService:ExampleService){
   this.exampleService.routeData().subscribe(data => {
       console.log(data)
   })
}
```